# Dynamic table modification using drop down lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to allow a user to make modifications to a matrix. In order to do these modifications, the user should be able to show each row using a options in drop down lists.

Below is a simple example to illustrate my purpose. The user is able to select a specific row using the drop down list (A, B or C) but for the moment, I can't change the content of this given row because the printed output contains formulas to the data matrix.

In summary, I would need to:

1. Print the content of a given row a data matrix
2. Allow user to change the content and dynamically change the content of data matrix.

[image]

Comment: VLOOKUP should do this. What have you tried?

Comment: what bit are you stuck with, the drop down or the formula ?

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't maybe clear. 
Part 1 works very well (I used the INDEX function) so when I select another element from the drop down list, I have the correct row printed.

However, I'm stuck for updating the data matrix when the user will enter a new value in the given printed row.

Comment: Formula will not be able to do what you want.  you will need VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with formulas, only with macros.

- As per [VBA excel - change two cell's values based on each other, when either cell is changed - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453372/vba-excel-change-two-cells-values-based-on-each-other-when-either-cell-is-ch)

  - Do the necessary changes in the predefined `Worksheet_Change` event handler sub in the `ThisWorkbook` module
  - Use `Application.Intersect` to check if any of your linked cells are in the changed range and make the necessary changes
- As per [vba - Why MS Excel crashes and closes during Worksheet_Change Sub procedure? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

  - To prevent an infinite loop, disable `Application.EnableEvents` before making changes and enable them after **and on an error**